# index type on possible undefined property

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use [advanced types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to write a function that, given a type and any two keys of it, must return an instance of a subtype, determined by the two keys. Example:

```
class MyClass {
    id: string
    name: string
    age: number 
}


const x = subtype(MyClass, 'id', 'name') 
// x type should be { id: string, name: string }

function subtype<Class, Key1 extends keyof Class, Key2 extends keyof 
    Class>(
    constructor: {new(): Class},
    key1: Key1,
    key2?: Key2,
): Pick<Class, Key1 | Key2> {
    const instance = new constructor()
    if (!key2) {
        return pick<Class, Key1 | Key2>(instance, key1)
    } else {
        return pick<Class, Key1 | Key2>(instance, key1, key2)
    }
} 
// the function above is my current implementation, not working
```

The problem is, because the 'key2' parameter is optional, typescript can not determine the type correctly using the Pick mapped type, and the result is that x has all the properties of the original class, like this:

```
const x = builder(MyClass, 'id', 'name') 
// x type is { id: string, name: string, age: number } (Wrong!)
```

Please, can someone give me a help on that? I really need to keep key1 and key2 independently of each other, and I also need key2 to be optional, so doing something like:

```
function builder<Class, Key extends keyof Class>(
    constructor: {new(): Class},
    keys: Key[],
): Pick<Class, Keys> { ... }
```

is not an option to me.

Comment: Could you also provide the signature for `pick` ?

Answer (score 0):

For your first function, the problem is that if you don't provide the type parameter it will be inferred as the maximal type (in this case any key of `T`) so the `Pick` will end up containing all properties. You can provide multiple signatures with and without the optional parameter:

```
function subtype<Class, Key1 extends keyof Class>(constructor: {new(): Class},key1: Key1): Pick<Class, Key1> 
function subtype<Class, Key1 extends keyof Class, Key2 extends keyof Class>
    (constructor: {new(): Class},key1: Key1,key2: Key2): Pick<Class, Key1 | Key2> 
function subtype<Class, Key1 extends keyof Class, Key2 extends keyof Class>
    (constructor: {new(): Class},key1: Key1,key2?: Key2): Pick<Class, Key1 | Key2> {
    const instance = new constructor()
    if (!key2) {
        return pick<Class, Key1 | Key2>(instance, key1)
    } else {
        return pick<Class, Key1 | Key2>(instance, key1, key2)
    }
} 

const x = subtype(MyClass, 'id', 'name') // will have only id and name
const x2 = subtype(MyClass, 'id')  // will have just id
```

As for the second example, it's syntactically incorrect, you have an array parameter and you don't invoke with an array. You can use rest parmaters and it will infer correctly:

```
function builder<Class, Key extends keyof Class>(
    constructor: {new(): Class},
    ...keys: Key[],
): Pick<Class, Key> { return  null; }


const xw = builder(MyClass, 'id', 'name')  // will have only id and name
```